# Example title in outer margins

Tags: environments, margins, examples

If I have large outer margins (even and odd pages) how I can put Example (and Solution) in both pages in the outer margins?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that considers example environments as theorems whose names have to be in the outer margin. There is a numbered and an unnumbered version. The use of ntheorem allows to cross-reference the examples and to make lists of examples.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsproc

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe,nohead,nomarginpar,textwidth =15cm, textheight=23cm,marginratio=3:5]{geometry}
\usepackage{ntheorem,ifoddpage} 

\makeatletter%
\newtheoremstyle{nonumoutermargin}%
{\item[\checkoddpage\ifoddpageoroneside\rlap{\hskip\linewidth\theorem@headerfont {\hskip18pt##1}}%
\else\llap{\theorem@headerfont{##1}\hskip6pt}\fi]}%
{\item[\checkoddpage\ifoddpageoroneside\rlap{\hskip\linewidth\theorem@headerfont   {\hskip18pt##1}}%
\else\llap{\theorem@headerfont{##1}\hskip6pt}\fi]}

\newtheoremstyle{outermargin}%
{\item[\checkoddpage\ifoddpageoroneside\rlap{\hskip\linewidth\theorem@headerfont {\hskip18pt##1\hskip\labelsep##2}}%
\else\llap{\theorem@headerfont{##1\hskip\labelsep##2}\hskip6pt}\fi]}%
{\item[\checkoddpage\ifoddpageoroneside\rlap{\hskip\linewidth\theorem@headerfont{\hskip18pt##1\hskip\labelsep##2}}%
\else\llap{\theorem@headerfont{##1\hskip\labelsep##2}\hskip6pt}\fi]}
\makeatother

\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}  
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremstyle{outermargin}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\theoremstyle{nonumoutermargin}
\newtheorem{unnumberedexample}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
First example. 
\end{example}
\clearpage
\begin{example}
Second example
\end{example}
\clearpage
\begin{unnumberedexample}
Third example
\end{unnumberedexample}
```

[image: Output: page 1]

[image: page 2]

[image: page 3]

Note there cannot be optional arguments as there is not enough space in a margin.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this command helps you with your problem:

```
\marginpar [left side notice] {right side notice}
```

Just put your notice in the brackets and you should be done.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.